# Find in Multidiamentional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an multi dimensional  array as

```
[
  {"EventDate":"20110421221932","LONGITUDE":"-75.61481666666670","LATITUDE":"38.35916666666670","BothConnectionsDown":false},
  {"EventDate":"20110421222228","LONGITUDE":"-75.61456666666670","LATITUDE":"38.35946666666670","BothConnectionsDown":false}
]
```

Is there any plugin available to search for combination of LONGITUDE,LATITUDE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array, that's an array of objects.

Comment: You could just loop over the data.

Comment: Doesn't look like a multidimensional array...

Comment: Sorry for that one. Its single diamentional only. But it consists of multiple data. Looping is taking too much of time search for the elements

Comment: As my array length is around 1800 elements its takes nearly 30-60 seconds to search for the elements

Comment: 60 seconds for loop through 1800 objects?! Impossible.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/mWg35/ looping twice over the elements takes like ~0ms. Even if I `console.log` the object in the second loop, it takes 55ms. But I saw in your code that you have a nested `for` loop. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i in VehCommLost) {
   var item = VehCommLost[i];
   if (item.LONGITUDE == 1 && item.LATITUDE == 2) {
      //gotcha
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Emmerman As my array length is around 1800 elements its takes nearly 30-60 seconds to search for the elements

Comment: @Techonthenet: Any "plugin" you can find for jQuery will do the same: looping.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to loop over an array.

Comment: @Techonthenet: What do you mean? Sample of what?

Comment: @Techonthenet. How much elements in `VehCommLost` and `midStopPoint` arrays?

Comment: Not using the for in loop the Array ?

Comment: @Emmerman: Because it will also loop over other enumerable properties of the array and not only over its elements. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in Using `for...in` to loop over arrays is very bad practice and  it is much slower than using a normal `for` loop.

Comment: @Felix Not much really (about speed). What about properties - of course you shouldn't use `for in` if you've modified Array prototype (or you can use `hasOwnProperty`), but if your code is simple and you use built-in Arrays, then `for in` statement is acceptable.

Comment: @Emmerman: Not sure which browser you are using, but in Chrome 10 on Mac OS X, `for...in` is about 70% slower than `for`, in Firefox 4 ~95% slower. Test it yourself: http://jsperf.com/array-for-in-vs-fo

Comment: @Techonthenet then if I've understood your code right, you have 1400*1383/2 = 968100 iterations. That's a little bit more than 1800. Uhm.. miss another increment - 484050 then.

Comment: @EmmerMan: another updates is the midstoppoints may be upto 10,500 also

Answer (score 0):

this is `json` string..which programming language u r using with js??

by the way try with [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: @Techon It's either a JSON string or an object. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Sime go here `http://www.jsonlint.com/` and paste the above string..output will b `valid JSON`

Comment: @Sime,    Its an JSon String And I have converted that into an Javascript array object using .Net   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "ComLost", strArrayDeclarations, True)

Comment: @Techon OK. Note that your question implies that the array is created via an array literal and *not* by parsing a JSON string.

Comment: It is created by parsing an object via json serializer

Answer (score 0):

Are the latitudes and longitudes completely random? or are they points along a path, so there is some notion of sequence?

If there is some ordering of the points in the array, perhaps a search algorithm could be faster.
For example:

- if the inner array is up to 10,000 elements, test item 5000
- if that value is too high, focus on 1-4999;
- if too low, focus on 5001-10000, else 5000 is the right anwser
- repeat until the range shrinks to the vicinity, making a straight loop through the remaining values quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it, it seems to me most likely that the solution to your problem lies in recasting the problem.
Since it is a requirement of the system that you are able to find a point quickly, I'd suggest that a large array is the wrong data structure to support that requirement. It maybe necessary to have an array, but perhaps there could also be another mechanism to make the search rapid.

As I understand it you are trying to locate points near a known lat-long.
What if, in addition to the array, you had a hash keyed on lat-long, with the value being an array of indexes into the huge array?

Latitude and Longitude can be expressed at different degrees of precision, such as 141.438754 or 141.4
The precision relates to the size of the grid square.
With some knowledge of the business domain, it should be possible to select a reasonably-sized grid such that several points fit inside but not too many to search.

So the hash is keyed on lat-long coords such as '141.4@23.2' with the value being a smaller array of indexes [3456,3478,4579,6344] using the indexes we can easily access the items in the large array.

Suppose we need to find 141.438754@23.2i7643 : we can reduce the precision to '141.4@23.2' and see if there is an array for that grid square. 
If not, widen the search to the (3*3-1=) 8 adjacent grids (plus or minus one unit).
If not, widen to the (=5*5-9) 16 grid squares one unit away. And so on...

Depending on how the original data is stored and processed, it may be possible to generate the hash server-side, which would be preferable. If you needed to generate the hash client-side, it might be worth doing if you reused it for many searches, but would be kind of pointless if you used the data only once.

Could you comment on the possibility of recasting the problem in a different way, perhaps along these lines?